# Create mongoose schema and insert document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongo and mongoose. I need to create schema from this object

```
trailers: [
{
id: 310131,
results: [
{
id: "564b9086c3a3686026004542",
iso_639_1: "en",
key: "gy_-pupKvxg",
name: "The Witch Official Trailer 1 2016 HD",
site: "YouTube",
size: 1080,
type: "Trailer"
},
{
id: "56aab2b19251417e110008b2",
iso_639_1: "en",
key: "feRupW34rUU",
name: "Trailer 2",
site: "YouTube",
size: 1080,
type: "Trailer"
}
]
}
],
```

Here is how I am doing it at the moment

```
// My Schema

var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ....
    ...
    ..
    .,
    trailers : [
        {
            id: Number,
            results : [
                {
                    id: String,
                    iso_639_1: String,
                    key: String,
                    name: String,
                    site: String,
                    size: Number,
                    type: String,
                }
            ],
            _id : false
        }
    ],
    ....
    ..
    .
});

var Movie = mongoose.model('Movies', movieSchema);

// Insert movie into schema and save to database
movies.forEach(function(m) {
    var movie = new Movie({
        ....
        ...
        ..
        .,
        trailers : m.trailers ? m.trailers : "",
        ....
        ...
        ..
        .
    });

    movie.save(function(err) {
        if(err) console.log('Error on save' + err);
    });
}, this);
```

But I am doing it wrong can anyone spot or tell me how to insert each movie into   schema object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `_id : false` What are you trying to do by doing this?

Comment: It prevents autocreateion of id on object... I think

Comment: Where did you read about this? _id is something that's a always present in a document in MongoDB. If you provide one, it'll not create one on it's own. But if you don't MongoDB creates it for you.

Comment: Ok nevermind the id but to you have an suggestion instead?

Answer (score 0):

Per [`mongoose subdoc`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html), please try to use `.push` to push `trailers` to `movies`. Here are the sample codes.

```
movies.forEach(function(m) {
    var movie = new Movie({
        ....
        //trailers : m.trailers ? m.trailers : "",
        ....
    });

    m.trailers.forEach(function(t){
        movie.trailers.push(t);
    });

    movie.save(function(err) {
        if(err) console.log('Error on save' + err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me this should be your schema :

```
var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
trailers: [
    ....
    ........
    ....
    _id: Number,
    results: [{
        iso_639_1: String,
        key: String,
        name: String,
        site: String,
        size: String,
        type: String
      }]
    ........
    ....
    ]
});
```

Looking at your object, what I suggest is : 
You should assign the `_id` field of the `trailers` array the `Number` that you currently assign to `id` field. And remove the id field from the schema.

`_id` field uniquely identifies a document inside a collection. So you should use it instead of `id` field that you created.

Secondly, you should let MongoDB create an `_id` field for your results array objects. That's why I haven't included an `_id` field in the results array object.

Next, to create new documents and save them in your collection, use your logic :

```
var Movie = mongoose.model('Movies', movieSchema);
// Insert movie into schema and save to database
movies.forEach(function(m) {
var movie = new Movie({
    ....
    ...
    ..
    .,
    (m.trailers) ? trailers = m.trailers : trailers = null,
    ....
    ...
    ..
    .
});

movie.save(function(err) {
    if(err) console.log('Error on save' + err);
});
}, this);
```

What's wrong with your logic is that you're trying to use ternary operator to check if m.trailers exist and if it does, you want to assign it to trailers array, and null otherwise. What you are using is :

```
trailers : m.trailers ? m.trailers : "",
```

What you should be using instead is :

```
(m.trailers) ? trailers = m.trailers : trailers = null,
```

Please do check it and let me know if it works.